# Cronjob to detect last modified files

Tags: php, apache, shell, server

I want to run a cronjob every minute to detect all files that were changed in the last minute in a specific directory (with about 300.000 inodes) and export this file list to a csv.

Is it possible to run an optimized command to do that? I cant run a "find" with sort flag in this directory cause it is huge and it will probably take more than 1 minute to run all files.

Is there any command I can do that? Or run any specific program on the background of the server that logs every changed file as it is changed? If there is a command using PHP to do this I am fine, I can create a cron to execute a PHP script, no problem.

Comment: If find doesn't work out, then probably IO is the bottleneck, so it is irrelevant if you use 'find' or some other method to determine the mtime of the files. Concentrate on a method to improve your IO.

Comment: What is writing to the files? Can it be done there?

Comment: Use `incrontab`. It works like normal `crontab` except on file events (such as a modify): http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man5/incrontab.5.html

Comment: I know I can use "find /directory -type f -mmin -1" BUT it takes about 3 minutes to show the list of files, even if the list has only 1 or 2 results. I am wondering if there is some kind of "trigger" or "function" that is called by the filesystem everytime a file is updated. Is there such a thing?

Comment: @JeremyHarris wow that looks promising! Could you elaborate it in an answer so I can accept it? Could you please tell me, for example, how to execute a "curl" to a specific URL everytime a file is changed "IN_MODIFY"? I would like to tell an external server that the file was changed in the local filesystem, so it would be nice to be able to CURL an external URL with the form http://www.example.com/file=/directory/file1.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a Linux utility called incron that can be used similar to normal cron, but rather than events being time based, they work off of inotify and are fired from file events.

You can find the Ubuntu man page here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man5/incrontab.5.html

I personally have not had to use it for anything too complex, but it roughly goes like this:

Install it:

```bash
sudo apt-get install incron
```

Open the editor to add an entry:

```bash
incrontab -e
```

Put something like this:

```bash
/var/www/myfolder IN_MODIFY curl https://www.example.com/api/file-updated/$#
```

The first part is the file or folder to watch. The second part is the event. And the third part is the command.

I *think* that `$#` is the placeholder for the file in question.

Comment: Heh, glad I could help :-)

Comment: This is really interesting. Thank you.